# GDI+ drawpath() and fillpath() overlaps when transparency is assigned

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, gdi+

the border and contents overlaps when drawpath() and fillpath() are both called and transparency is assigned.
the problem is not neglectible when strokewidth is large.
there is a third color on the overlapped part.
The problem occurs when printing to pdf via microsoft print to pdf.
Althought a third party pdf creator can be used to avoid the prolbem, I still want the problem solved when printing via microsoft print to pdf.
Is there even a way to dig into pdf creation process of ms to pdf?
thanks in advance.